# asp form has a button, but the button seems to not call any function, still download is happening

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to scrape a website with an asp form. There is an image input, which has no onclick or any tag to it, so I don't know what is it calling on a click. Still if I click on it, it downloads a file. What does exactly triggers the download. I was thinking about async jQuery but really could not find a solution.
The html tag of the input looks the following:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptItem$ctl00$lnkStatus" 
id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptItem_ctl00_lnkStatus" 
src="images/download.ico" style="border-width:0px;height:30px;border- 
width:0px;">
```

And from the posted headers I can not see anything which would trigger a download. What could cause a download to happen?

Comment: An onclick event might've been attached to it using Javascript, not C#.  Try doing a global search for the id or even name of the button to see what comes up.

Comment: An `<input type="image"` will normally cause your page to post back, just like any other button. So perhaps it ties to some server-side event which causes a download to occur.

Comment: I tried for searching such javascript function, but i will try it again.
How can I see what kind of event is 'posted' to the server side?

Comment: `<input type="image"` performs a `form.submit` (like `<input type="submit"` ) that post the whole form back to the server. If the server returns a file, it will be downloaded.